# Symbolic Variable Substitution: Python

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I wish to find the value of the given equation by substituting the value of the symbolic variable 'x'. However, the output still contains the variable:

```
import math
from sympy import *

m = var ('x')
x = m
i = 1

while i <= 100:
    m = sin(m)
    i = i + 1

i = 1

while i <= 7:
    k = diff(m,x)
    i = i + 1

print(k.subs(x, 0))
```

Output:

```
cos(x)*cos(sin(x))*cos(sin(sin(x)))*cos(sin(sin(sin(x))))*cos(sin(sin(sin(sin(x)))))*cos(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x))))))*cos(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x)))))))*cos(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x))))))))*cos(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x)))))))))*cos(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x))))))))))
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: you want the value of the 7th derivative of 100 chained sin functions at x=0? (actually you only get the first derivative in your second loop...). please state your problem in a clear way.

Comment: `m`, `x` and `k` don't vary in your second loop.

Comment: You can avoid introducing a python variable `x` and simply use `k.subs('x', 0)`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes, I want the 7th derivative of 100 chained sine function at x=0.

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on the title, use

```
k.evalf(subs={x: 0})
```

But I really think you should work on your code. It is not Pythonic and probably does not serve the purpose you want.